# Python iterating a list based a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my current snippet:

```
l = ['i', 'b', 'c', 'a', '3', 'a', '7', 'a', '9', 'k', 'a', '66', 'k', 'd']

new_list = []
a = {}
for i in range(len(l)):
    if 'a' == l[i]:
        a['plus_line'] = l[i+1]
        new_list.append(a)


print(new_list)
```

I am expecting output like this below:

```
[{'plus_line': '3'}, {'plus_line': '7'}, {'plus_line': '9'}, {'plus_line': '66'}]
```

But I am getting:

```
[{'plus_line': '66'}, {'plus_line': '66'}, {'plus_line': '66'}, {'plus_line': '66'}]
```

I am trying to achieve when `a` will be in the list, then the next item of the `a` will be the value of the `dict`.

Comment: your expected and actual output are the same

Comment: Hi sactual output is: `[{'plus_line': '66'}, {'plus_line': '66'}, {'plus_line': '66'}, {'plus_line': '66'}]`

Comment: `a = [{'plus_line': y}  for x, y in zip(l, l[1:]) if x == 'a']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

itzhaki explains the problem with your code, here's another possible way of doing it:

```
l = ['i', 'b', 'c', 'a', '3', 'a', '7', 'a', '9', 'k', 'a', '66', 'k', 'd']

result = [{'plus_line':l[n+1]} for n, i in enumerate(l) if i == 'a']

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'plus_line': '3'},
 {'plus_line': '7'},
 {'plus_line': '9'},
 {'plus_line': '66'}]
```

Comment: kinda weird to accept an answer that shows an alternative implementation without explaining the error but what do I know :(

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you're mutating the `dict` named `a`.
Instead you could do something like:

```
l = ['i', 'b', 'c', 'a', '3', 'a', '7', 'a', '9', 'k', 'a', '66', 'k', 'd']

new_list = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    if 'a' == l[i]:
        new_list.append({'plus_line': l[i+1]})

print(new_list)
```

This will create a new `dict` instead of mutating an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You simply needed to reset your `a = {}` at the start of each loop (not outside the loop). By initializing it outside the loop, you created one dictionary named `a`, which has only one key, `plus line` which keeps getting assigned a new value.

```
l = ['i', 'b', 'c', 'a', '3', 'a', '7', 'a', '9', 'k', 'a', '66', 'k', 'd']

new_list = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    a = {}
    if 'a' == l[i]:
        a['plus_line'] = l[i+1]
        new_list.append(a)


print(new_list)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[{'plus_line': '3'}, {'plus_line': '7'}, {'plus_line': '9'}, {'plus_line': '66'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['hi there'] = 23
>>> d['hi there'] = 24
>>> d
{'hi there': 24}
```

You're overwriting the key `'plus_line'` of dictionary `a`.

Items you're appending in list `new_list` are referencing to dictionary `a`. Thus the problem.

Possible solution for that can be:

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> for i in range(len(l)):
...     if 'a' == l[i] and i < len(l) - 2:
...             new_list.append({'plus_line':l[i+1]})
... 
>>> new_list
[{'plus_line': '3'}, {'plus_line': '7'}, {'plus_line': '9'}, {'plus_line': '66'}]
```

Comment: Maybe just limit the for loop to `for i in range(len(l)-1):` ?